# Let H be the orthocenter of the acute triangle ABC. Extend the altitude AD until it intersects the circumcircle of triangle ABC at F. Show that BH=BF

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

I have been doing the problem for an hour and have gotten nowhere, can anyone either give hints OR help guide me through the proof. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, I would suggest showing your attempts else it may be closed because this LOOKS like an exercise, see the site policy on homework and exercises

Comment: This is a very classical result (http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/AltitudeAndCircumcircle.shtml)

Comment: @Cursed1701 sorry, do you know how I can upload a picture of my attempt? I have it on my iphone I just do not know how to upload!

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie I appreciate it!!

Comment: Upload it to imgur then post the link in the question and someone can format it in

Comment: Thanks for saving my butt lol ! @Cursed1701

Answer (score 1):

Because if $BK$ is an altitude of our triangle we obtain:
 $$\measuredangle BFA=\measuredangle BCA=90^{\circ}-\measuredangle DAC=\measuredangle AHK=\measuredangle BHF,$$
which gives $\measuredangle BFH=\measuredangle BHF$ and we are done!